# WPF DataGrid custom grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, datagrid, grouping

I'm kinda new to WPF and need some advice on how to implement a custom grouping setup for the DataGrid. I know the normal wpf DataGrid can do grouping, but potentially transferring 500k records over a crappy third world network and then have the crappy, cheap, and 5+ year old pc crawl through the data is not an option. In africa companies would generally invest in semi decent server setups, but when it comes to the end user machines... sadly anything that can still power on will do. So I need to do all the work on the server to the point that the end user pc only has to do the bare minimum to render only what is needed on the screen. This is the case for Winforms, wpf, and even HTML.

First, we already have a web front end that is working well. It's kinda our proof of concept version. Currently I'm working on reworking most of the back end logic to run in a wcf service and then have web and wpf front ends connect to the same service.

I already do my grouping server side along with the sort order and then only pull the few records I need to send to the front end out of the result set. I mark each row as either a Header, Data, or Footer and then on the client I just run from the top of the result set to the bottom and render each row appropriately. Below is an example of what we more or less want and the page count was set to 10. Note that it's just random junk data.

[image: Example]

What is important to note here is that only records that are part of an Open Group is sent to the client. The 5 closed groups in the image don't have any child records on the client front end. Only when a group is Open will the result set coming from the server contain child records to be rendered on the screen. If you count the group headers and detail rows you will see it adds up to 10. Group footers don't count to the page size limit. So in total I only sent 20 (Footers are in the result set) rows of information from the server to the client and not the 1000 records with 61 columns that's actually in the table.

Doing it like this is waaaaayyyy faster than potentially sending 10 000 records to the user machine and then do the sorting, grouping, and paging on the user machine.

Could I use what I have, or something like it, in a wpf datagrid? How do I get the datagrid to render 3 different types of rows as shown above?
Or should I not look at the DataGrid and do something else to render the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just make my own "DataGrid" using the WPF Grid with column and Row definitions. The other option seems to be the WPF Table which seems to work kinda like the HTML table.

I now just have to implement my own Drag and Drop to change column order and to allow sorting on column header clicks. Already figured out the Drag and Drop so progress is being made.